# Going through a range of numbers in python that each are supposed to be typed into a searchbox on a website

Tags: python, search, range

maybe someone can help me, Im pretty new to coding
Im trying to go through a range of numbers that are each supposed to be typed into a searchbox on a website.
That is my sad try so far, does anyone have an idea? I guess its gotta be a little more complex than this

[image]

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchbar.send_keys('Numbers')
```

would send the word "Numbers" to the search bar, if you want to send the numbers themselves you could use a format string:

```
f"{Numbers}"
```

the f in front of the string "" indicates that it's going to be a format string and the {} evaluate your variables. So:

```
a = hello
print(f"{a} world!")
>>> hello world!
```

Though in that case that alone would only send the list to the searchbar so you could use a loop to get over the numbers one by one:

```
for i in Numbers:
     searchbar.send(str(i))
```

or you could "".join(Numbers) into one string and send them all at once. Kinda depends on why you're doing it and what you mean to accomplish with it.

Comment: Thanks ma! I didn't get back to it. I'll let you you know if it worked :)